# Issue trying to fit n points inside a rectangular area

Tags: matlab, geometry, temperature

I'm facing the following problem: given the dimension of a rectangular area, i.e. base and height, I have to fit inside it an also given quantity of point as depicted by my draw:

Bear in mind that points are not necessarily equally spaced, but they have to be arranged in a manner that each row and column has the same quantity of points.

[image]

Just to provide you with some context, the rectangular area is a representation of a rectangular plate with border conditions of temperature and I'm supposed to calculate the temperature distribution inside it (each point temperature will be computed afterwards by means of Gauss-Seidel method).

**NOTE: **My program is being coded in MATLAB.

Comment: What do you mean by "fit points"?

Comment: If you have *N* points, you can certainly make one row with *N* points or one column with *N* points. (If *N* < 2, these two solutions are the same.) If *N* ≥ 2 and is composite, there are other solutions.  Is this useful to you? If not, what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you will be working exclusively with a rectangular domain, then `meshgrid` should take care of your needs:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]; %node x-discretizations (evenly spaced)
y = [1,4,9,16]; %node y-discretizations (unevenly spaced)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) %creates the discretized domain.
```

`x` is a vector that contains the x-coordinates (first dimension) over which you are trying to solve your problem. `y` is the same thing as `x` but for the second dimension.

`X` and `Y` are matrices that together encode the (x,y) coordinates of the nodes.`meshgrid` won't care about node spacing, just make sure that `x` and `y` are of the same `size`.